# If I have Transactional Producer in Kafka can I read exactly once messages with Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to have Exactly-once semantics, but I don't want to read message with Consumer. I'd rather read messages with Kafka Streams AP. If I add **processing.guarantee=exactly_once** to Stream configuration, will exactly-once semantics be kept?

Comment: I don't see it really feasible however this might help you https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly-once processing is based on a read-process-write pattern. Kafka Streams uses this pattern and thus, if you write a regular Kafka Streams application that writes the result back to a Kafka topic, you will get exactly-once processing guarantees.

Note, that side-effects are not covered by this guarantee. Also note, that there might be retries internally in case of failure. Exactly-once implies, that the result you see in the output topic, is the same as if no error (and thus not retries) would have happened.

For more details, you might want to watch a talk recording about exactly-once guarantees in Kafka. There are multiple available at Confluent webpage *(disclaimer: I am an employee at Confluent)*: https://www.confluent.io/resources/

Comment: Hey Matthias. I guess my question is not correct. I write message with Transactional Producer into topic. I assume if I have idempotent Kafka API Consumer - I will get exactly-once message.

What if I from the same topic that I write with Transactional Producer, will read not with Idempotent Consumer, but using Kafka Streams API? Will Producer and Streams read have same transaction? I want to have exactly once when processing messages with Streams from transactional Producer topic

Comment: There is nothing like a "idempotent consumer". Note, that when you consumer records (using KafkaConsumer or Streams API) you don't see any transactional boundaries. Reading is agnostic to transactions with this regard. The consumer and Streams API can only guarantee to not return aborted transactions, but transactional boundaries are not visible on the read path. It's similar to a DB: if one client updates 2 out of 5 rows in a table, after the commit, a reader cannot tell which rows were modified by the transaction. A transaction is not a write-read pattern, but a read-process-write pattern.

Comment: I guess I just completely misunderstand transaction concept in Kafka. So transaction **is not** considered committed when Consumer commits offset os a last message in transaction? Transaction considered committed before Consumer reads last message in transaction?

Comment: A transaction is complete, when the Producer commits the transaction. Ie, the commit happens on the write path, not the read path. A transaction in Kafka, is an atomic multi-partition write. Please watch the talks recording I pointed out. It's explained there.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for your time and patience. Will watch talks also to get more understanding!