# Kafka exactly_once processing - do you need your streams app to produce to kafka topic as well?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams app consuming from kafka topic. It only consumes and processes the data but doesn't produce anything.

For Kafka's exactly_once processing to work, do you also need your streams app to write to a kafka topic?

How can you achieve exactly_once if your streams app wants to process the message only once but not produce anything?

Comment: Its not mandatory to produce message to topic in case of KafkaStream

Comment: is this different then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698695/if-i-have-transactional-producer-in-kafka-can-i-read-exactly-once-messages-with

Comment: Hi Parthsavi , Let me put my thought in this..

Answer (score 1):

I am not conflicting on exactly-once stream pattern because that's the beauty of Kafka Stream however its possible to use Kafka Stream without producing to other topics.

Exactly-once stream pattern is simply the ability to execute a read-process-write operation exactly one time. This means you consume one message at a time get the process and published to another topic and commit. So commit will be handle by Stream automatically one message a time.
Kafka Stream achieve these be setting below parameters which can not be overwritten

> - isolation.level: (read_committed) - Consumers will always read    committed data only
> - enable.idempotence: (true) - Producer will always have idempotency    enabled
> - max.in.flight.requests.per.connection" (5) - Producer will always       have one in-flight request per connection

In case any error in the consumer or producer Kafka stream always retries a specific configured number of attempts.
KafkaStream doesn't guarantee inside processing logic we still need to handle e.g. there is a requirement for DB operation and if DB connection got failed in that case Kafka doesn't aware so you need to handle by your own.

As per pattern definition yes we need consumer, process, and producer topic but in general, it's not stopping you if you don't output to another topic. Still, you can consume exactly one item at a time with default time interval commit(DEFAULT_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS) and again you need to handle your logic transaction failure by yourself
I am putting some sample examples.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        Properties props = getStreamProperties();
        KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(Pattern.compile("topic"));
        textLines.process(() -> new ProcessInternal());

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("Completed VQM stream");
            streams.close();
        }));

        logger.info("Streaming start...");

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        
        
        class ProcessInternal implements Processor<String, String> {
        private ProcessorContext context;
        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            // Any code for clean up would go here. 
        }
        @Override
        public void process(String key, String value) {
        ///Your transactional process business logic
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

***Providing “exactly-once” processing semantics really means that distinct updates to the state of an operator that is managed by the stream processing engine are only reflected once. “Exactly-once” by no means guarantees that processing of an event, i.e. execution of arbitrary user-defined logic, will happen only once.***

Above is the "Exactly once" semantics explanation.

It is not necessary to publish the output to a topic always in KStream application.

When you are using KStream applications, you have to define an applicationID with each which uses a consumer in the backend. In the application, you have to configure few 
parameters like `processing.guarantee` to `exactly_once` and `enable.idempotence`

Here are the details :
https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#processing-guarantee

Answer (score 0):

## What you are trying to do is not possible, at least not with vanilla Kafka

I took the below screenshot from the free Confluent eBook *Designing Event Driven Systems*. It is helpful to illustrate the point made below.

[image: Kafka]

Quote from a [relevant article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/chain-services-exactly-guarantees/):

> **What Can’t Transactions Do?**
>
> There are a few limitations or potential misunderstandings of transactions that are worth noting. Firstly, they only work in situations where both the input and the output goes through Kafka. If you are calling an external service (e.g. via HTTP), updating a database, writing to stdout, or anything other than writing to and from the Kafka broker, transactional guarantees won’t apply and calls can be duplicated. So much like using a transactional database, transactions only work when you are using Kafka.

---

I do not fully understand what the other two answers are claiming:

- One answer talks about `enable.idempotence` which is a **producer** property, not a **consumer** property, and alone **does not guarantee exactly once processing**.
- It guarantees that in the case of transient network failures, the fact that producers will automatically retry sending event data by default will not result in more than one copy eventually being persisted to Kafka.
- It works by performing de-duplication on the Kafka side

The Kafka [documentation on Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) says as much:

> **Exactly-once semantics:** even if a producer retries sending a message, it leads to the message being delivered exactly once to the end consumer. Exactly-once semantics is the most desirable guarantee, but also a poorly understood one. **This is because it requires a cooperation between the messaging system itself and the application producing and consuming the messages.** For instance, if after consuming a message successfully you rewind your Kafka consumer to a previous offset, you will receive all the messages from that offset to the latest one, all over again. **This shows why the messaging system and the client application must cooperate to make exactly-once semantics happen.**

- The other answer talks about Kafka Streams, which are a technology built on top of Kafka, but is it's own separate thing.
- Full disclosure: I do not know that much about Kafka Streams as I have never used them.
- You tagged your question with the Kafka Streams tag, but from the context it seems like this is not sufficient because you do not have a producer side, where data is being produced to Kafka.
- Assuming I understand correctly, Kafka Streams apps persist data in a local RocksDB instance, so that they can restore their state in the case of failure.
- Let's see why this doesn't work without a producer:

## Example

Let's imagine the simplest possible application which consumes data from Kafka but does not produce. What should this app do?

- It should read individual events from an input Kafka topic
- It should not contain any internal state
- It should print some information about each event to stdout. (Why? Because there isn't any simpler example, other than to discard the data completely, in which case the example is pointless.)

Let's now consider what happens in two possible scenarios relating to how Kafka will commit data.

- The problem will arise because your system (the app you are building) is an independent system to the Kafka system.
- Therefore you cannot process data and commit to Kafka in a way which ensures exactly once processing in all cases. Let's see why:

### Option 1: Commit before printing

In this scenario let's assume we will issue a commit to Kafka after consuming an event but before printing it to the screen.

Here's what happens:

1. Consumer consumes 1 event from Kafka
2. Consumer commits. If the application now dies we will not read this event again on restart
3. Print event data to stdout

Clearly if the power goes out or our application for some reason quits after performing (2) but before performing (3) the data for the event will **never** be printed out to stdout, even after a restart.

### Option 2: Commit after printing

In this scenario, let's assume we will issue the commit after consuming an event and printing it to the screen.

Here's what happens:

1. Consumer consumes 1 event from Kafka
2. Print the event data to stdout
3. Commit

In this case, if the application dies and restarts after performing (2) but before (3) then when the app restarts we will print the **same event data as before resulting in the data for one event being printed twice**.

This demonstrates why in general it is not possible to perform exactly once processing without integrating a whole system with Kafka.

In this example, I chose the "example problem" of printing data to screen. However, we could equally as well have chosen "sending data to a database" as an example problem.

In some cases, you may be able to architect your way around to re-obtain exactly once semantics. Possible approaches might include:

- Making use of the inbox/outbox design
- Associating UUIDs with events and performing manual checks with some other system like a database to see if the event has been "seen" before

## Further Reading

- https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/